# Conditional validation on rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation

I have an api which contains a method that accepts an object as a request body. What I would like to do is apply conditional validation. Looking at the code below:

```
@Override
@PostMapping(value = "/private/getUsers/",
        produces = {"application/json"},
        consumes = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUsers(@ApiParam(value = "Request object for users", required = true)
                                                 @Valid @RequestBody USerType userType) {

   //do stuff here
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Object, HttpStatus.OK);
}

class UserType {
  TypeEnum typeEnum
  String name;
  String adminId    

 //getters and setters
}
```

So if the UserType object that is passed through contains a TypeEnum that is equal to admin, i would like to do validation that ensures a adminID is passed through, if the TypeEnum passed in is of type cashier i would  not like to enforce this validation

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validtation using `@AssertTrue`.
Try with this class:

```
class UserType {
  TypeEnum typeEnum
  String name;
  String adminId    

 //getters and setters

@AssertTrue
    public boolean isValid() {
        if (TypeEnum.admin == typeEnum) {
            if (check admin id not blank){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```